# unbound local-zone and local-data: am I doing it right?

Tags: domain-name-system, internal-dns, unbound

I'm playing with `unbound` to forward DNS queries to an authoritative DNS server, cache them, and also add additionals local informations.
My config is pretty straightforward:

`/etc/unbound/unbound.conf`:

```
server:
  ... # all default settings
  include: "/etc/unbound/unbound.conf.d/*.conf"

forward-zone:
  name: "."
  forward-addr: 1.1.1.1   # authoritative server
```

Then I want to add some `local-data` in several `local-zone`, for instance:

`/etc/unbound/unbound.conf.d/foobar.org.conf`

```
server:
  local-zone: "foobar.org." transparent
  local-data: "foobar.org. 3600 IN SOA admin.foobar.org. admin.foobar.org. 1710435698 86400 3600 3600000 300"
  local-data: "foobar.org. 3600 IN NS admin."
  local-data: "foobar.org. 3600 IN MX 0 foobar.org"
  local-data: "foobar.org. 3600 IN A 12.34.56.78"  
  local-data: 'system.at.foobar.org. 14400 IN TXT "contact@foobar.org"'
  local-data: "private.foobar.org. 3600 IN A 10.0.1.2"
  local-data-ptr: "10.0.1.2 private.foobar.org."
  local-data: "public.foobar.org. 3600 IN A 98.76.54.32"
  local-data-ptr: "98.76.54.32 public.foobar.org."  
  ...
```

This setup works as excepted. `local-data` records are well resolved, same for the PTR, the `TXT` etc.

But is this really the way `unbound`'s `local-zone` & `local-data` needs to be configured ?

If I compare this setup with a "classic" `bind` zone file:

```
$ORIGIN foobar.org.
$TTL    3600
@   IN  SOA admin.foobar.org. admin.foobar.org. (
        1710435698      ; Serial
        86400           ; Refresh
        3600            ; Retry
        3600000         ; Expire
        300 )           ; Negative Cache TTL
@       IN  NS  admin.
@       IN  MX 0    foobar.org.
@       IN  A   12.34.56.78
system.at           IN  TXT "contact@foobar.org"
private             IN  A   10.0.1.2
public              IN  A   98.76.54.32
```

In this `bind` zone :

- I don't have to repeat the TTL for each record
- I don't have to repeat the zone name for earch record
- for each record, I *know* they're part of the zone

So my question is: is my `unbound` setup ok, or did I missed something in the way to configure `local-zone` & `local-data`; and link records to a zone ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `local-data` option doesn't use "classic" zone files because it was *never meant to* host a zone. Unbound is a caching resolver first and foremost (and was meant to go together with NSD for authoritative hosting); the option you're using is only there to let you **override** the DNS replies on a name-by-name basis. (Which is why you have local-zone modes like 'transparent' – normal authoritative zones wouldn't do that.)

So yes, this is the way `local-data` needs to be configured, because you're trying to make it do something that it wasn't really made for.

Current versions of Unbound (apparently as of 1.7.x) do have support for authoritative hosting, but you configure it using a separate `auth-zone:` section:

```
auth-zone:
    name: "example.com"
    zonefile: "example.com.zone"
    for-downstream: yes
    for-upstream: yes
```